# Adding placeholder to ChoiceField in Django?

Tags: django

In my forms.py I have a simple form class defined as:

```
SAMPLE_STRINGS = ['aa','ab','bb','c0']

class IndicatorForm(forms.Form):
    chosen_number = forms.IntegerField(label='Please select a value')
    chosen_string = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SAMPLE_STRINGS, label='Please select a string', required=True)
```

I want to add a placeholder for both fields. For the first one, it was easy:

```
chosen_number = forms.IntegerField(label='Please select a value', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 0}))
```

But for the ChoiceField, I didn't have any luck. I tried using `widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=...)` but that removes the choices and transforms the field into a simple text field. `widget=forms.ChoiceInput` and `widget=forms.ChoiceField` do not work either.

How can I add a placeholder saying "Select..." to my ChoiceField?

Comment: Do you want an initial value for the field i.e. one of the values in `SAMPLE_STRINGS`? If so there's a form field argument called `initial` for that - see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#initial)

Comment: @elyas, no, I would like a placeholder saying "Select..." to my ChoiceField. By default, Django sets the first choice as the initial value, so in this case "aa".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) Django performs this operation automatically and gives you an optional override argument `empty_label`.

For a [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) you have to add your empty label manually. If you want the same default empty label we can insert it by [copying what Django does](https://github.com/django/django/blob/59552bea5790c97be0da0a6f16ccd0189857c7a7/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L863):

```py
from django.db.models.fields import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH

...

chosen_string = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH + SAMPLE_STRINGS, label='Please select a string', required=True)
```

For a custom empty label you can simply prepend a two-tuple to your `SAMPLE_STRINGS` list:

```py
SAMPLE_STRINGS = [('', 'My empty label'), 'aa', 'ab', 'bb', 'c0']
```

The two-tuple ensures `value=""` in the resulting `<option>` generated.